# AmE_ thank you + simple past or present perfect

Tags: grammar, tense, present-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

Context: I am a new student of a class. There is a friend, she has always helped me since I joined the class. Now I am still in the same class with her.
I feel grateful and just want to say thank you to her.

> (1) Me: Thank you for what you **did** for me, Jane. I hope that our
> friendship will last forever.

> (2) Me: Thank you for what you **have done** for me, Jane. I hope that
> our friendship will last forever.

No matter if Jane keep helping me or not, I can use either tense. Right?

Any difference between them?

Comment: To me, _what you did_ suggests that she no longer does it.

Comment: Have you been taught when to use the simple past and when to use the perfect? The usual rules should help you here.

Comment: @StuartF, yes, I been studying these two tense for a long time, but sometimes I still can’t grasp the difference between them. I had a post here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606897/ame-the-use-of-the-simple-past-and-the-present-perfect-in-the-us-for-repeated-a. I think that I can use either tense here without much difference, but I am not sure, so I want to hear more about your opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Thank you for what you **did** for me*" usually refers to one single action Jane did. If it indicates a series or pattern of behaviour, it's from so long ago that it feels like one single event now.

"*Thank you for what you **have done** for me*" refers to either a single event, or a series or pattern of actions, possibly continuing to the present. If the actions don't continue to the present, then the *present* aspect is that the action still has an effect now.